# Nhibernate QueryOver - .SelectCount() with predicate

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

I need to select count of row with a condition:

Query to collect the full count:

```
var searchs = searchQuery.SelectList
                    (list => list

                                .SelectGroup(order => order.Id).WithAlias(() => groupResult.GlobalId)
                                .SelectCount(() => _transaction.ReturnStatus).WithAlias(() => groupResult.DeclineCount)
                    )
```

I need count of transactions that equals 201. Something like this:

```
.SelectCount(() => _transaction.ReturnStatus == 201).WithAlias(() => groupResult.DeclineCount) //runtime error
```

Thanks in advance!

PS:
Original SQL Query:

```
SELECT TOP 100
        globalOrd.ID AS GlobalId ,
        SUM(CASE WHEN transact.returnStatus = 201 THEN 1
                 ELSE 0
            END) AS DeclineCount
FROM    Orders.Global globalOrd
        INNER JOIN Orders.TransactionDetail transactDet ON globalOrd.ID = transactDet.DetailID
        INNER JOIN Orders.[Transaction] transact ON transactDet.TransactionID = transact.ID
GROUP BY globalOrd.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the total count in the same query you can simply add in the restriction before the SelectList:

```
var searchs = searchQuery.SelectList
    (list => list
                .Where(() => _transaction.ReturnStatus == 201)
                .SelectGroup(order => order.Id).WithAlias(() => groupResult.GlobalId)
                .SelectCount(() => _transaction.ReturnStatus).WithAlias(() => groupResult.DeclineCount)
    )
```

If however, you want both the total and the restricted count, you would have to use a SqlProjection for the latter doing something like:

```
 SUM(CASE {alias}.ReturnStatus WHEN 201 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, I need "both". I updated the question with original SQL. I still believe to do it without SqlProjection - it seems to be so simple operation and queryover couldn't do it?